# I am having trouble understanding constructor parameter values relating to coordinate detection

Tags: java, processing

```
package tictactoe;

import processing.core.PApplet;


public class TicTacToe extends PApplet {

    int cols = 3;
    int rows = 3;
    int h;
    int w;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main("tictactoe.TicTacToe");

    }

    public void setup() {
        //Organization for size of columns and rows
        w = width / cols;
        h = height / rows;
    }

    public void settings() {
        size(300, 300);

    }


    public void draw() {
        //Draw a tic-tac-toe grid
        background(255);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                stroke (0);
                noFill();
                rect(i*w, j*h, w, h);

            }
        }





        }
    public class GridSquare{
        //Game state (x's and o's), variables, etc.
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float w;
        public float h;
        public int state;
        public void drawTurn() {
            if (state == 0) {
                ellipse(x+w/2,y+h/2,w,h);

            }
            if (state == 1) {
                line(x,y,x+w,y+h);
                line(x+w,y,x,y+h);


            }


        }
        //Trouble understanding Grid Detection

        void onClick(int clickedX, int clickedY, int turn) {
            if (clickedX > x && clickedX < x + w && clickedY > y && clickedY < y + h) {

        }
    }
    }
}
```

I am having trouble understanding the grid detection if statement. Since the parameters x, y, w, and h all had a semi colon when being defined in the GridSquare class, wouldn't that mean that those variables all equal 0? In that case, wouldn't the if statement be checking if the click x integer is greater than 0, and clicked x is less than 0 (x) + 0 (w)? Or am I wrong, and are the variables representing integers previously defined in the code?

Comment: Is your code working, and the issue is just that you are trying to understand _why_ it works, or is there some other problem?

Comment: Is that all of your code? `GridSquare` is not being used anywhere.

Comment: Tim, yes my code is working. And yes, I am just trying to understand why it works :)

Comment: Sweeper,  I understand Grid Square isn't being used yet, as I am not finished writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more easily understood if you think about having multiple games (GridSquares) going on at the same time, each with a border around it, and each being drawn on the same panel. The check is simply determining if the click in the panel is valid for that game (GridSquare). With multiple games at once, each one would have a different value for x and y; imagining two games, side by side, the first would probably have (x=0, y=0), but the second game would be at least 300 units (pixels, perhaps) to the right, giving values (x=300, y=0).

Comment: This is true, though how does it add the specific coordinates for the parameters x and y relating to each other square? By default, since in the class GridSquare x and y were not set as a value, they equal zero, meaning that this code can only detect a click in the first box (0, 0), from my understanding at least.

Comment: In other words, how does it detect which X to and Y input to use, as when the boxes are generated, the values change until all boxes are generated

Comment: It's a guess, but it looks like the settings() method calls the size() function and sets up the square to be 300x300.